# Data type without input value and multiple primitive types

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, gadt

Firstly, I'd like to apologize if I'm repeating this but I searched everywhere without finding an answer to my question.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
data TestType = Nothing | Int | Float deriving (Show)

jaykay :: TestType -> [Char]
jaykay Int = "This is an int"
jaykay Float = "This is float!"
jaykay a = "Nothing matched.."

main :: IO()
main = do
  jaykay [PLACE HOLDER]
```

Clearly this type does not have any value constructor(s). So what I thought I could do here is create a type from primitive types that would normally hold any values of the specified ones in the definition right? My question is about how would I construct an instance of this type and also if this definition isn't correct how would I achieve what I described earlier?

Thanks

Comment: check [`sqlValue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.1/docs/src/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html#line-201) from `DataBase.HDBC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your type *does* have value constructors -- three of them, in fact, named `Nothing`, `Int`, and `Float`. So, one could write, for example

```
main = putStrLn (jaykay Int)
```

and running the program would print out `This is an int`. However, I suspect that you wanted your constructors to accept arguments of the related types; so you *probably* wanted to write something like

```
data TestType = Nothing | Int Int | Float Float
```

so that values of type `TestType` constructed with the `Int` constructor would contain an additional value of type `Int`; and likewise those constructed with the `Float` constructor would contain a value of type `Float`. (N.B. there are two separate namespaces here! There is a type-level name `Int` which comes from the `Prelude` and you have now also defined a value-level `Int` whose type is `Int -> TestType`.)

An example of using this more exciting new data type would be this:

```
jaykay (Int i) = "got the Int " ++ show i
jaykay (Float f) = "got the Float " ++ show f
jaykay a = "dunno lol"

main = putStrLn (jaykay (Int 3))
```

Running this program would print out `got the Int 3`.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Indeed what I wanted to do is form a type that would handle one of the certain primitive types. Again thanks for the detailed answer.